# C++ Macro's Token-Paster as argument of a function

Tags: c++, macros

I was searching for a while on the net and unfortunately i didn't find an answer or a solution for my problem, in fact, let's say i have 2 functions named like this :

1) `function1a(some_args)`

2) `function2b(some_args)`

what i want to do is to write a macro that can recognize those functions when feeded with the correct parameter, just that the thing is, this parameter should be also a parameter of a C/C++ function, here is what i did so far.

```
 #define FUNCTION_RECOGNIZER(TOKEN) function##TOKEN()

void function1a() 
{

}
void function2a() 
{
}

void anotherParentFunction(const char* type)
{
    FUNCTION_RECOGNIZER(type);
}
```

clearly, the macro is recognizing "functiontype" and ignoring the argument of anotherParentFunction, i'm asking if there is/exist a trick or anything to perform this way of pasting.

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Instead of macro you should use function overloading. Just give function1a and function1b the same name: function1.

Comment: i want to avoid overloading and finding a solution without using it.

Comment: For this task overloading is natural way to go and must be used. Macro are not for that and can't be used because macro does not know about types.

Comment: Are you thinking that if you call `anotherParentFunction("1a")` then you'll end up calling `function1a()`, but that if you call `anotherParentFunction("2a")`, you'll end up calling `function2a()`?  If so, you've sadly misunderstood the operation of the C++ Preprocessor.  That's a run-time decision which cannot be coded by the preprocessor — doubly not if instead of string literals you use a variable containing data supplied by the user, for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As long as the values are known at compile time, it is possible.

Comment: @Zereges: I'll be curious to see your solution, then.  Let me know (an @ comment) when you've added it (though I'm off to bed shortly).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler With a bit of help (optimalization) from the compiler, of course. Or you can use templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a macro: Skip the anotherParentFunction() function and use the macro directly instead. When called with constant strings, i.e.

```
FUNCTION_RECOGNIZER( "1a");
```

it should work.

A more C++ like solution would be to e.g use an enum, then implement anotherParentFunction() with the enum as parameter and a switch that calls the corresponding function. Of course you need to change the enum and the switch statement then every time you add a new function, but you would be more flexible in choosing the names of the functions.

There are many more solutions to achieve something similar, the question really is: What is your use case? What do want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In 16.1.5 the standard says:

> The implementation can process and skip sections of source files conditionally, include other source files, and replace macros. *These capabilities are called preprocessing, because conceptually they occur before translation of the resulting translation unit.*

[emphasis mine]

Originally pre-processing was done by a separate app, it is essentially an independent language.

Today, the pre-processor is often part of the compiler, but - for example - you can't see macros etc in the Clang AST tree.

The significance of this is that the pre-processor knows nothing about types or functions or arguments.

Your function definition

```
void anotherParentFunction(const char* type)
```

means nothing to the pre-processor and is completely ignored by it.

```
FUNCTION_RECOGNIZER(type);
```

this is recognized as a defined macro, but `type` is not a recognized *pre-processor* symbol so it is treated as a literal, the pre-processor does not consult the C++ parser or interact with it's AST tree.

It consults the macro definition:

```
#define FUNCTION_RECOGNIZER(TOKEN) function##TOKEN()
```

The argument, literal `type`, is tokenized as `TOKEN`. The word `function` is taken as a literal and copied to the result string, the `##` tells the processor to copy the value of the token `TOKEN` literally, production `functiontype` in the result string. Because `TOKEN` isn't recognized as a macro, the `()`s end the token and the `()` is appended as a literal to the result string.

Thus, the pre-processor substitutes

```
FUNCTION_RECOGNIZER(type);
```

with

```
functiontype();
```

So the bad news is, no there is no way to do what you were trying to do, but this may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and perhaps there's a solution to what you were trying to achieve instead.

For instance, it is possible to overload functions based on argument type, or to specialize template functions based on parameters, or you can create a lookup table based on parameter values.